# Apache Phoenix UPSERT timeouts on large data

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera-cdh

Exception in thread "main"

```
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: 
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixIOException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:    
Mon May 09 20:45:17 PDT 2016, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=214280: row '�.�A`' on tabl..
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: improved formating

Comment: It fails after 60 seconds, what is "large data" for you? What do you do with the data?